# How to Get HTML table datas(from each row) into servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I want to get the values in my html table(from each row) to the servlet when i submit the form. How can it be done? Pls help me with a solution.

```
<form name="form1" action="serv" method="POST">
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>NAME</th>
                <th>AGE</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Dev</td>
                <td>13</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shartt</td>
                <td>15</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" name="submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: your format was wrong, use new one

Comment: Sorry.. Which formt??

Comment: when you code there should be a format.. I correct your one. accept it.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML you dont have any form elements. Try with something like this:

```
<form name="form1" action="serv" method="POST">
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>NAME</th>
                <th>AGE</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Dev</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="age" value="13"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shartt</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="age" value="13"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td clospan="2"><input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" name="submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</form>
```

Comment: So.. Anyone pls help me to get the values from each row in my servlet